# JQuery Flot plothover event in Bar chart

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a Bar chart made using JQuery Flot. I want that when I pass the mouse over some bar, show me a tooltip.

take a look at some definitions that I did in my bar chart options.

```
grid: {
   hoverable: true,
   borderWidth: 0,
   color: '#838383',
   clickable: true
}
```

When I load all data and plot the chart, I bind the `plothover` event like a put below

`$(dataParameters.containerSuccess).bind("plothover", self.funcaoPassarMouse);`

My `plothover` function

```
self.funcaoPassarMouse = function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
            y = self.CommaFormatted(item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2));
            var mes = self.ObtemMes(item);
            self.exibirTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, "R$ " + y + " em " + mes);
        }
    } else {
        $("#tooltip").remove();
        previousPoint = null;
    }
}
```

I have a lot of charts that uses JQuery Flot, and in all of them, the plothover event whose uses this function, works very well, except in Bars charts.

In Bars charts I saw that the `item` parameter comes with a `null` value and I don't know why.

Can anyone help me ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7snkmshf/2/)

Comment: Could you produce a fiddle (or even better a stack snippet) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @MattBurland Sure, give me some minutes that I'll let the fiddle's link here

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/mwyeck3q/1/

Comment: @MattBurland Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/7snkmshf/1/

Comment: I think the problem is with the way `time` as an axis setting interacts with the bar chart (note the skinny bars). If you change the type of the axis to "category", then you get fat bars that detect correctly (but lose the time formatting). Also note that it does detect the first and last bars if you hover just off the edge of the chart, which is wierd.

Comment: @MattBurland I also think that the problem is with `time`, that uses another Jquery Flot plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with how the `time` axis interacts with the bar graph. The simplest solution maybe to convert your times to strings and make your axis a `category`. For example:

```
    var data = [
        [new Date(1388534400000).toDateString(), 10],
        [new Date(1391212800000).toDateString(), 8],
        [new Date(1393632000000).toDateString(), 4],
        [new Date(1396310400000).toDateString(), 13],
        [new Date(1398902400000).toDateString(), 17],
        [new Date(1401580800000).toDateString(), 9]
    ];
```

And then:

```
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                align: "center",
                barWidth: 0.05     // set this to whatever makes them skinny enough for you
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "categories",
            //... etc
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7snkmshf/4/

Note: dealing with time zones is left to the reader.